# How to print specific word in <li> in website python

Tags: python, html, find

This is the html code:

```
<li><span>hello</span>world</li>

<li><span>YYY</span>XXX</li>
```

How can I print only the word after "hello"? in this case"world".
Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2


opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')] 
url = ""
response = opener.open(url)
page = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
text = soup.get_text()
print text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this HTML `<li class="clearfix"><span class="numLabel">שער בסיס</span> 19,030</li>`

and this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')] 
url = "http://localhost:8000/test.html"
response = opener.open(url)
page = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
lis = soup.findAll('li')
for li in lis:
    span = soup.find('span', { "class" : "numLabel" })
    if span.text == u"שער בסיס":
        text = span.next_sibling
        print text.encode('utf8').strip()
```

Outputs: 19,030

Tested on MacOS, Python 2.7.13, BeautifulSoup 4.6.0

We first find the `li` tag, then the `span` tag within that `li`. Then we get the next sibling, in your example the text outside the `span` tag.

Comment: Quickly tested the above code and it appeared to work fine using a local file. Perhaps with your data you have some unicode characters? Try this `print text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`

Comment: Yep. the data have unicode characters. Now it worked, but it didn't print nothing..

Comment: Oh wait, maybe it didn't print because the text with unicode characters?
@Stu

Comment: This now may be an issue with your console printing unicode characters. Perhaps try `print text.encode('utf8')`. Most consoles can handle UTF-8. Also can you provide the actual data you are trying to parse in your question?

Comment: Yep, it worked, but in very strange letters:
"Î£ÎóÎ×ÎòÎô ÎöÎæÎÖÎ¬"
But there's other problem, these strange letters according to my example are the "Hello" and not "world" which I need.
In the html it looks like this:
                <li class="clearfix"><span class="numLabel">שער 
                בסיס</span>
                19,030</li>

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I used to test. Can you try this as a test and see what result you get.

Comment: Never mind, I downloaded lxml, but the output is:
http://prntscr.com/ff4uqi

Comment: Edit: Keep in mind that there are a lot of <li> and <span> in the website, but I want to find:
<li class="clearfix"><span class="numLabel">שער בסיס</span> 19,030</li>
And only from this line of code print "19,030".

Comment: Ok perhaps it's matching on the wrong `li`. You can try using `span = soup.find('span', { "class" : "numLabel" })` instead which will match on the first span with numLabel as the class. Hopefully then the next sibling will be
 the number you are looking for. Also try printing out `lis` to see if it's the `li` you're looking for.

Comment: Well it works as well, but as I said there are a lot of span class "numLabel" which means it's matching on the wrong span..
Maybe we can try to loop over all classes numLabel to search "שער בסיס"?

Comment: Yep you can use findAll rather than find to loop over all the `li`s. I've updated my answer again, but I'm afraid I can't continue further. I think your original question has been answered, please mark it as such.

Comment: Never mind, I did it. answer:
span = soup.findAll('span',{"class":"numLabel"})[1]
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The word 'hello' is inside a `span` tag. In this case, the first `span` tag in your html code.

To get access to a specific tag using bs4 you can do the following:

```
soup.find('span') # finds the first 'span' occurrence in your html document.
soup.findall('span') # finds every span occurrence in your html document and returns a list where each element contains the span element and its content.
```

On top of that you can use the method 'get_text' which will give you the text inside a tag. Example:

```
print(soup.find('span').get_text())
>>> hello
```

Comment: Well I'm actually trying to find a value.
In the website it looks like this:
Hello: world
How can I print only the word after "Hello"?